# Java: "Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp"

Tags: java, class, command-prompt

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp"
```

Hi. I have JDK 1.8 installed. After compiling a HelloWorldApp program into a class file, I tried running  the `java -cp . HelloWorldApp` command but it gave the error above.
I set  the directory correctly to the folder I'm working with that has the compiled .class file (Saved initially in Notepad). I read that we should delete the `java.exe`,`javaw.exe`, and `javaws.exe` file in the System 32 folder (My `PATH` variable uses that directory). So instead of getting that the `java -cp.` function is not recognized in command prompt, I now get the above error. Thank you.

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package helloworldapp;

/**
*
* @author Uset
*/
public class HelloWorldApp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("HelloWorld!");
}

}
```

Comment: Did you try Googling the error? If so, why does what that suggested not work? Remember this isn't an "answer my questions" site, this is a "here's what I've done, help me with the last bit" site. If you've fixed the common causes and that doesn't fix it, then you can post here, explaining what you've done so far. Otherwise, go back and do the research, and that should be able to fix it.

Comment: Do you have a package specified in your class? If Yes then use that e.g. my.package.HelloWorldApp.

Comment: can you paste project structer??

Comment: I tried but they consult the issue with the command "java" and I'm stuck at the "java -cp" command. And most problems addressed concern the CLASSPATH and other variables which I can't quite read.@QPaysTaxes Sorry, I'm a beginner . In the code I can read "package helloworldapp;" Does that help? -JSS Didn't change anything except add the simple code "System.out.println("HelloWorld!");"     -Prashant

Comment: You need to run `javac` if I recall correctly. Make sure to add it to your `PATH` as well. I'm not sure. I use project managers like Eclipse for all of my work.

Comment: I already compiled the project and class file created. Tutorial on Oracle says to run "java -cp . HelloWorldApp" @QPaysTaxes

Comment: ...Sorry. Like I said, I'm not terrible good at the command-line. Try using `HelloWorldApp.class` instead, adding the path in front, just different permutations

Comment: Didn't work :( But still help with understanding Stack Overflow posts much appreciated :) @QPaysTaxes

Comment: I you use a package name, you have to use the fully qualified name of your main class ie. `helloworldapp.HelloWorldApp` when you run it

Comment: also, if you have 'helloworldapp' package it needs to be in a folder that is named that way as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion, it seems you have this kind of java class:

```
package helloworldapp;

public class HelloWorldApp {
    // class contents
}
```

The file needs to be in a subfolder matching the package name, so 'helloworldapp':

```
> dir
helloworldapp
> dir helloworldapp
HelloWorldApp.java
```

Then you can compile and run it like:

```
javac helloworldapp/HelloWorldApp.java

java helloworldapp/HelloWorldApp
```

Comment: /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
I have this instead of //class contents. Do I continue?

Comment: @Houssam7111 please add your java code to the question so we can see it. `// class contents` was just a placeholder for any contents you might have

Comment: Added it to the post. @eis

Comment: @Houssam7111 the class looks ok, so my instructions should work